# pytest --cov shows detailed report in command line, but not during githook pre-commit

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, code-coverage, pytest-cov

When I run `pytest src/packages --cov --cov-branch --cov-report term-missing`, I get a detailed report with Stmts | Miss | Branch | BrPart | Cover | Missing as shown in screen shot below:

[Report in Command Line Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U9qv.png)

However, when I run `pre-commit run pytest-cov-src-packages` (or git commit) with the pre-commit hook shown below, I just get a "pytest-cov-src-packages..................................................Passed" statement in the command line. No report or anything. Just passed.

```
  - id: pytest-cov-src-packages
    name: pytest-cov-src-packages
    language: system
    entry: pytest src/packages --cov --cov-branch --cov-report term-missing 
    types: [python]
    stages: [commit]
    pass_filenames: false
    always_run: true
```

Is there any reason why running pytest in command line vs. firing off the entry: snippet from the pre-commit yields a different result? I would love to have the detailed report in the command line as shown in the image working during the pre-commit process as part of the git commit.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't include *pictures* of text (or link to pictures of text). Just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any reason why running pytest in command line vs. firing off the entry: snippet from the pre-commit yields a different result?

Because `pre-commit` is often configured to run many tests, it is designed to provide summary output by default. Any output produced by your `pre-commit` entries is discarded for successful tests; you will only see the output in the event of a failure.

If you *always* want to see the output, you can run `pre-commit` with the `-v` flag.

Compare:

```
$ pre-commit run --all-files
pytest-cov-src-packages..................................................Passed
```

With:

```
$ pre-commit run --all-files -v
pytest-cov-src-packages..................................................Passed
- hook id: pytest-cov-src-packages
- duration: 0.21s

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 1 item

test_foo.py .                                                            [100%]

---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.10.4-final-0 -----------
Name          Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------
test_foo.py       2      0      0      0   100%
---------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL             2      0      0      0   100%


============================== 1 passed in 0.04s ===============================
```